# How to store skip lists on disk?

Tags: database, tree, disk, skip-lists, physical-design

How do you store a skip list on disk?

- How do you arrange the nodes to take advantage of file system pages?
- Do you use a file for each page, one file for everything, or something else?
- The linked question mentions disk pointers - how do they help?

---

*After posting this on the Database Administrators stackexchange site I realized that it's more of an algorithm question and less of a database administration question, so I moved it over here.*

*Also, the community seems to think that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53689043/how-to-write-an-on-disk-skip-list) is a bad question, although it asks basically the same thing. This question is more direct.*